# Clicking a Dynamically Changing ID Element with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I have this piece of HTML code:

```
<li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-12" tabindex="-1"><a>2</a></li>
<a>2</a>
</li>
```

The id "ui-id-12" is dynamically changing with the number being the part that is changed so I was wondering how I would go about finding this element using Selenium & XPaths. I was considering finding the element using the content within the anchor element tags but was not sure if this was smart so I have come here instead to ask what would be the best option.

Comment: Try to reach parent tag and traverse to child you want

Comment: Duplicate of https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18342/how-to-handle-dynamic-changing-ids-in-xpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the *id* attribute of the `<li>` element i.e. **ui-id-12** is dynamic. So to find the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li.ui-menu-item[id^='ui-id-']")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[starts-with(@id, 'ui-id-') and @class='ui-menu-item']")
  ```